# WCF - CODEGEN: Generating message contract since message FileRequest has headers

Tags: wcf

I am aware that there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375446/add-service-reference-is-generating-message-contracts) with no solution.

I'm working on a WCF streaming service over HTTP.

Here are my `MessageContract`

```
[MessageContract]
public class FileRequest
{
    #region Message Header

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public Credential Credentials { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Message body

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Ctor

    // ...

    #endregion

}

[MessageContract]
public class FileRequestResponse
{
    #region Message Header

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public FileInfo FileHeader { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public OperationResult<bool> OperationResult { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Message Body

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream FileStream { get; set; }

    #endregion


    #region Constructor

    // ...

    #endregion

}
```

Here is my `ServiceContract`

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "https://service.contract.example.com")]
public interface IUpdateService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "GetUpdates")]
    OperationResult<List<FileInfo>> GetUpates(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo, Credential credential);

    [OperationContract(Action = "GetFile")]
    FileRequestResponse FileRequest(FileRequest fileRequest);
}
```

Now the question is why I am getting this error:

> // CODEGEN: Generating message
>   contract since message FileRequest has
>   headers

When I add my service reference. The end result is that the service contract wraps the FileRequest operation into a wrapper which I do not want.

```
public FileInfo FileRequest(Credential Credentials, FileInfo, out OperationResult<bool> OperationResult, out System.IO.Stream FileStream)
```

**NOTE:**
I have not checked the "Always generate message contracts" in the service reference.

Comment: It's not an error - it's just an informational note

Comment: I am aware this is not an error because it will still compile, I merely expressing it as an error because it is an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to use the `IsWrapped` attribute on the message contract:

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
```

Not 100% sure which one you'll need (`true` or `false`) but that's one of the options you could try.

Also, another observation: I think it's a bit risky to have a method called `FileRequest` and a message contract which also is called `FileRequest`.

The generally accepted best practive would be to have a method `GetFile`, a request message for that called `GetFileRequest` and a response message type `GetFileResponse`. Do not use the same names for different things.

Comment: I have tried IsWrapped = false/true with no difference in result. I have changed MessageContract FileRequest name with no result either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set `[MessageContract(IsWrapped=true)]` for **all the message contracts** in the service and then try generating the proxy .